# One query to get total # records for each day in a month

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Scenario:

I have a table of registrations and there is a datetime column.

I want to display a bar graph on a webpage showing number of registrations per day for the current month.

How can I do that with one query? i.e. get back a resultset with a field for each day (of current month) with the total number of registrations that day

Answer (score 5):

```
select day(Date), count(*)
from table
where month(Date) = month(NOW()) and year(Date) = year(NOW())
group by day(Date)
```

"Where" clause selects the current month. You can use `count(whatever)` or `count(distinct whatever)` instead of `count(*)`...

Comment: Might be better to use a date range since `month(date)` and `year(date)` won't be indexed.

Comment: Like this you don't get all days, just the ones with records in the DB. Is there any way to get all days and in case there are no records, get 0?

Comment: @Steve, good question actually, I've come across it many times during coding... I guess the best solution is to do this outside of SQL, in presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
SELECT Day, COUNT(*)
FROM XXX_Users
GROUP BY "date extracted from datetime" as Day
```

To extract the date from datetime you could use the DATE function:

```
SELECT Day, COUNT(*)
FROM XXX_Users
GROUP BY DATE(created) as Day
```

Or you can create a Stored Procedure to enclose all the logic inside